# Earth & Sun Models Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've tried debugging this multiple MULTIPLE times but can't find a solution to this. So basically, my Earth model and Sun model are not being rendered properly. They are appearing as a dull filled colour. Despite having a texture added to the sphere, the texture is not loading onto it.

I'd say to look at lines 104 - 141 as that's where I'm creating the Sun and Earth models.

Also, would love some help on my Animate function.

Current code:

```js
// Standard Variables / To be changed later.
var scene, camera, renderer //, container;
var W, H;
var delta = Math.delta;

W = parseInt(window.innerWidth);
H = parseInt(window.innerHeight);


camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, W / H, 1, 1000000);
camera.position.z = 36300;
scene = new THREE.Scene();

// renderer
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(W, H);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Adding Stars.
var starsGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var starsMaterial = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xbbbbbbb,
  opacity: 0.6,
  size: 1,
  sizeAttenuation: false
});
var stars;

// Adding stars to the Scene.
for (var i = 0; i < 45000; i++) {
  var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
  vertex.x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  vertex.y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  vertex.z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  vertex.multiplyScalar(7000);
  starsGeometry.vertices.push(vertex);
}

stars = new THREE.ParticleSystem(starsGeometry, starsMaterial);
stars.scale.set(50, 50, 50);
scene.add(stars);


// ------------------------------------------------------------
var starsGeometry2 = new THREE.Geometry();
var starsMaterial2 = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xbbbbbbb,
  opacity: 1,
  size: 1,
  sizeAttenuation: false
});
var stars2;

// Adding stars to the Scene.
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
  vertex.x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  vertex.y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  vertex.z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  vertex.multiplyScalar(7000);
  starsGeometry2.vertices.push(vertex);
}

stars2 = new THREE.ParticleSystem(starsGeometry2, starsMaterial2);
stars2.scale.set(70, 150, 100);
scene.add(stars2);

// Ambient light to the Scene.
var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222);
scene.add(ambient);




// ------------------------------------------------------------

//Sun
var sun, gun_geom, sun_mat;
sun_geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2300, 80, 80);
//texture.anisotropy = 8;
sun_mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
sun = new THREE.Mesh(sun_geom, sun_mat);
sun_mat = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/sunmap.jpg');
//sun_mat.bumpMap  = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/sunmap.jpg');     
//sun_mat.bumpScale = 0.05;
//var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/sunmap.jpg');
scene.add(sun);


var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2300, 80, 80);
var texture2 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/earthmap1k.jpg');

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  map: texture2,
  emissive: 0xffffff
});
var earth = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);


//earth_mat = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
//earth = new THREE.Mesh(earth_geom, earth_mat);

scene.add(earth);

var t = 0;

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  y = parseInt(event.offsetY);

});

// Call Animate function within load function.

animate();

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  sun.rotation.y += 0.001;
  earth.rotation.y += 1 / 16 * delta;

  //camera.position.y = y * 5;
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);


  t += Math.PI / 180 * 2;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

// everything now within `onload`
```

```css
body {
  background: whitesmoke;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/109/three.min.js"></script>
```

What I mean:

[image: Dull]

Comment: any console error from the browser?

Comment: @ChrisChen No errors, just multiple suggestions.

Comment: I got 404 Not Found on your two texture image in your snippet. They are not loaded by the look of it as well.

Comment: Those are not suggestions. They are errors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run your code I get all these errors

```
THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial has been renamed to THREE.PointsMaterial.
THREE.ParticleSystem has been renamed to THREE.Points.
THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial has been renamed to THREE.PointsMaterial.
THREE.ParticleSystem has been renamed to THREE.Points.
THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture has been deprecated. Use THREE.TextureLoader() instead.
THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture has been deprecated. Use THREE.TextureLoader() instead.
```

You should fix those errors

Otherwise not sure what this code was supposed to do

```
sun_mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
sun = new THREE.Mesh(sun_geom, sun_mat);
sun_mat = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/sunmap.jpg');
```

It makes a material, passes it to `THREE.Mesh` then tries to make a texture that is not used and it re-assigns `sun_mat` to that texture but `sun_mat` is used by nothing else.

I changed the code the code to this

```
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

//Sun
var sun, gun_geom, sun_mat;
sun_geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2300, 80, 80);
sun_mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  emissive: 0xffffff,
  emissiveMap: loader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/textures/waterdudv.jpg'),
});
sun = new THREE.Mesh(sun_geom, sun_mat);
scene.add(sun);


var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2300, 80, 80);
var texture2 = loader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/textures/planets/earth_atmos_2048.jpg');

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  emissiveMap: texture2,
  emissive: 0xffffff,
});
var earth = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(earth);
```

You'll also notice above I changed from using `map` to `emissiveMap`. You need to add some lights other than the `AmbientLight` if you want `map` to work.

Then the code has the earth and sun the same size and stacked on top each other. I moved the earth

```
earth.position.set(5000, 0, 0);
```

Then in the render loop there's this code

```
earth.rotation.y += 1 / 16 * delta;
```

but delta is defined as

```
var delta = Math.delta;
```

There is no such thing as `Math.detla` so `delta` is undefined which means `earth.rotation.y += 1 / 16 * delta;` just becomes `NaN` which means the math for the earth breaks so it disappears.

I just set `delta = 1`.

You might find [this articles](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-scenegraph.html) helpful with your three.js learning as they are up to date with version 109 (they aren't using the outdated classes the code you posted referenced)

```js
// Standard Variables / To be changed later.
var scene, camera, renderer //, container;
var W, H;
var delta = 1.;//Math.delta;

W = parseInt(window.innerWidth);
H = parseInt(window.innerHeight);


camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, W / H, 1, 1000000);
camera.position.z = 36300;
scene = new THREE.Scene();

// renderer
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(W, H);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Adding Stars.
var starsGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var starsMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  color: 0xbbbbbbb,
  opacity: 0.6,
  size: 1,
  sizeAttenuation: false
});
var stars;

// Adding stars to the Scene.
for (var i = 0; i < 45000; i++) {
  var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
  vertex.x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  vertex.y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  vertex.z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  vertex.multiplyScalar(7000);
  starsGeometry.vertices.push(vertex);
}

stars = new THREE.Points(starsGeometry, starsMaterial);
stars.scale.set(50, 50, 50);
scene.add(stars);


// ------------------------------------------------------------
var starsGeometry2 = new THREE.Geometry();
var starsMaterial2 = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  color: 0xbbbbbbb,
  opacity: 1,
  size: 1,
  sizeAttenuation: false
});
var stars2;

// Adding stars to the Scene.
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
  vertex.x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  vertex.y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  vertex.z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  vertex.multiplyScalar(7000);
  starsGeometry2.vertices.push(vertex);
}

stars2 = new THREE.Points(starsGeometry2, starsMaterial2);
stars2.scale.set(70, 150, 100);
scene.add(stars2);

// Ambient light to the Scene.
var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222);
scene.add(ambient);




// ------------------------------------------------------------
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();


//Sun
var sun, gun_geom, sun_mat;
sun_geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2300, 80, 80);
sun_mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  emissive: 0xffffff,
  emissiveMap: loader.load('https://i.imgur.com/gl8zBLI.jpg'),
});
sun = new THREE.Mesh(sun_geom, sun_mat);
scene.add(sun);


var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2300, 80, 80);
var texture2 = loader.load('https://i.imgur.com/BpldqPj.jpg');

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  emissiveMap: texture2,
  emissive: 0xffffff,
});
var earth = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
earth.position.set(5000, 0, 0);

scene.add(earth);

var t = 0;

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  y = parseInt(event.offsetY);

});

// Call Animate function within load function.

animate();

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  sun.rotation.y += 0.001;
  earth.rotation.y += 1 / 16 * delta;

  //camera.position.y = y * 5;
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);


  t += Math.PI / 180 * 2;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

// everything now within `onload`
```

```css
body {
  background: whitesmoke;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/109/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Really appreciate the help! Really new to THREE.js so trying my best.